# Swiper me da el error "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Tags: javascript, consola, swiper

No se que ocurre con swiper, estoy copiando de un video literalmente lo mismo y no funciona. Esta todo bien linkeado y las clases/id tienen los nombres correctos. adjunto el JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".coming-container", {
spaceBetween: 20,
loop: true,
autoplay:{
    delay: 55000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
},
centeredSlides: true,
breakpoints:{
    0:{
        slidesPerView: 2,
    },
    568:{
        slidesPerView:3,
    },
    768:{
        slidesPerView:4,
    },
    968:{
        slidesPerView:5,
    },
}, 
})
```

Supuestamente el error viene de aca:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".coming-container", {
```

Comment: Y estás seguro de que tienes un div con clase `.coming-container`?  Estaría muy bien que proporcionases un [mre], por poder ver cual es el problema... porque el objeto de configuración parece correcto a simple vista

Comment: Hola Agustin, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la sección de tu html que tiene el elemento .coming-container?. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, elimina esta pregunta para evitar los votos negativos, es más fácil editar tu pregunta que hacer una nueva ;)